# Owl carousel not showing up

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to get this owl thing going and its really pushing me back on a project.

```
<html>    
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
</script>
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg8.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg9.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg11.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "img/bg12.jpg"></div>
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d3uzm34t/

Comment: Please try to put script code under the slider div area. ( ( Just below body.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code, you missed autoplay prop in the configuration

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoPlay: 1000,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I must be doing something wrong I added the autoplay function like you said and still nothing.

Comment: Check the code snippet embeded here, its running properly. Did you add any lib which is conflicting ?

Comment: Nope, I actually copied exactly what you did, did not work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.. very strange.

Comment: When I remove the js files (jquery library and owl.carousel.min.js) the images show but just like one on top of the other, I think it has something to do with the jquery.

Comment: Got it to work! I tried your code again and it worked thanks! do you recommend to use these libs that you are using?

Comment: And why wasnt working when I used the local js and css files, I dont understand :/

Comment: Also I can use all the carousels but I dont get the "previous" and "next" buttons. Do you know how could I implement that?

Comment: May be the version you downloaded is having some problem. I recommend you to use the lib i included.

Comment: I want to use these files:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

So its not working the way I need it to work.

Comment: upload those files in some place or let me the version of bootstrap and owl carousel css. it will help me to debug further

Comment: bootstrap version is 3.3.4 and jquery is 1.10.2